# Java 8 stream vs jpa postrgresql orderby. What is better for performance?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, jpa, java-8

I'am using jpa entitymenager with postgresql and java 8. 
I need to show some data order by name.

What is faster and have better perfomance:

make a Query to the database like

```
@Query("select t from Table t order by t.someField ")
```

or just get all records from the database and sort them using java 8 stream api like

```
 someCollection.stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getSomeField()
            .compareTo(e2.getSomeField())).
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that Java will outperform postgres - but the best thing to do is to measure both options..

Comment: If nothing else, PostgreSQL can do an index-ordered read, which JPA sure can't

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do this with Java on a table with 100 million rows (probably 10 million would already be too many)

Comment: Why don't just try and measure on your own data?

Answer (score 2):

In general if you can sort with SQL, just go ahead. If your sorting column is indexed, then sorting will be trivial: PostgreSQL will just read this index which already contains the resulting order. Even if your sorting column is not indexed, DBMS may do it more effectively. For example, it's not necessary to hold the whole rows in memory during sorting inside DBMS, you just need the values from the sorted column and row ID. After you get the properly ordered list of row IDs, you can send the rows to the client in streaming way. Also when sorting really big tables DBMS may dump some data to hard-disk to reduce memory usage.

Note that DBMS sort is performed on DBMS side which can be completely different server, thus the resulting speed also depends on whether DBMS server or application server is more powerful or has more free resources right now.

If you want to sort the results in Java, probably it would be better to do in-place sort using `someCollection.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getSomeField()))` (assuming that your `someCollection` is the `List`). This will reduce the consumed memory and number of times your data should be copied. The in-place sorting is the most effective for array-based lists like `ArrayList`.

Also it should be noted that sorting results may be different as they may depend on current DBMS collation (in Java you just sort strings by UTF-16 code point values unless custom [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) is used).

Comment: Agree. "if you can sort with SQL, just go ahead" web has plenty of samples how to filter / sort etc on the client side. Supposedly OK (over tiny data sets), but bad practice in general